# How do I set my primary graphics card?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, dual-gpu

I have Acer Aspire V5-552G laptop and it has dual graphic cards 1. on board graphic (Radeon HD 8650G) and 2. dedicated graphic card (Radeon HD 8750M) but the on board graphic card is my primary (which is suck) and I want my dedicated graphic card to be the primary. I tried searching in my BIOS and I couldn't find it. Any idea how to do this? thanks

Comment: This requires the installation of the Acer supplied GPU drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Your dedicated graphics card is always primary unless otherwise notated...

Comment: but when I checked on dxdiag it show my on board graphic card instead :(